# Retrieving a Movie's Showtimes grouped by Theater: Movie->Showtimes<-Theater in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-1.3

When you view a movie, I want to show the showtimes (movie_times table) organized by Theater.  I can get all the data just fine, but it's returning the Theater data with EVERY MovieTime like this:

```
[0] =>
    [Movie] =>
        [name] => Herp de Derp
    [MovieTime] =>
        [0] =>
            [datetime] => 2011-07-06 18:30:00
            [Theater] =>
                [name] => Awesome Cinemas
                [address] => 1234 Street Ln
        [1] =>
            [datetime] => 2011-07-06 20:30:00
            [Theater] =>
                [name] => Awesome Cinemas
                [address] => 1234 Street Ln
        [2] =>
            [datetime] => 2011-07-06 20:30:00
            [Theater] =>
                [name] => Crappy Movies 10
                [address] => 678 Avenue St
```

As you can imagine, there is a TON of duplication with the theater data.

Is there a way I can get this same data, but instead, get the Theater data grouped with the movie_times within it like this?:

```
[0] =>
    [Movie] =>
        [name] => Herp de Derp
    [Theater] =>
        [0] =>
            [name] => Awesome Cinemas
            [address] => 1234 Street Ln
            [MovieTime] =>
                [0] =>
                    [datetime] => 2011-07-06 18:30:00
                [1] =>
                    [datetime] => 2011-07-06 20:30:00
                [2] =>
                    [datetime] => 2011-07-06 22:30:00

        [1] =>
            [name] => Awesome Cinemas
            [address] => 1234 Street Ln
```

My associations are the following:

```
Movie hasMany MovieTime
MovieTime belongsTo Movie

Theater hasMany MovieTime
MovieTime belongsTo Theater
```

As you can see, there's no direct link between Movie and Theater - it's using the `MovieTime` as a go-between.  The associations make logical sense (to me at least) - but if I have to change them to a different (but also logical) setup, I'm certainly willing to hear it.

I'm using this to get my data currently:

```
        $data = $this->find("first", array(
            'conditions' => array(
                array('Movie.slug' => $slug)
            ),
            'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug', 'url', 'runtime'),
            'contain' => array(
                'MovieTime' => array(
                    'fields' => array('datetime', 'screen_number'),
                    'Theater' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id', 'slug', 'name', 'address', 'phone'),
                        'City' => array(
                            'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'st')
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the GROUP BY. You just need to add 'group' => 'Put here de Model.Id' into your find.

Try this:

```
$data = $this->find("first", array(
            'conditions' => array(
                array('Movie.slug' => $slug)
            ),
            'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'slug', 'url', 'runtime'),
            'contain' => array(
                'MovieTime' => array(
                    'fields' => array('datetime', 'screen_number'),
                    'group' => 'Theater.id',
                    'Theater' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id', 'slug', 'name', 'address', 'phone'),
                    'City' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'st')
                    ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

For more information, check this two links:

- http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-group-by-in-cakephps-new-release-part-2:4850d2c9-edbc-4f0e-9e0e-07d64834cda3
- http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/06/03/new-way-to-group-by-in-cakephp

Comment: When I do that, I get:  Unknown column 'Theater.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Theater is my model name, and id is the primary key.  I don't want to group by MovieTime.id - that's the opposite of what I want.

Comment: I change my first answer, try that.

Comment: Error:  Unknown column 'Theater.group' in 'field list'

Comment: Back to this one again:  Unknown column 'Theater.id' in 'group statement'

Comment: Your Model Theater isn't associated with Movie right? Only with MovieTime, MovieTime model exist to connect the two of them right?

Comment: See what I changed in the answer. (I put 'group' => 'Theater.id', right before is associated Model, the MovieTime.)

Comment: Now it's giving this error:  Unknown column 'MovieTime.group' in 'field list'

Comment: put before, insted. like:

`'group' => 'Theater.id',`
`'fields' => array('datetime', 'screen_number'),`

Group above Fields

Comment: I am desperate xD I can't help you more, try to read the links I put in the end. In my case that helped me a lot. Sorry ford bad answer :S